# Functional Dependency Reduction

Tags: functional-dependencies

I'm supposed to find the minimal cover for this set of FD's. Please let me know if my answer is correct.

1. XZ->Z
2. XZ->Y
3. XZ->B
4. YA->C
5. YA->G
6. C->W
7. B->G
8. XZ->G

My answer:

1. X->Z (deleted Z attribute, trivial FD)
2. Z->Y (deleted X, since it entails X->Z->Y from 1.)
3. Z->B (same here)
4. YA->C
5. YA->G
6. C->W
7. B->G
8. (Deleted, since X->Z->B->G)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to me that the first one is not correct:

- `XZ->Z` does not imply anything, since XZ contains Z, thus it is trivial.

Comment: So should I delete that dependency and leave X in 2. and 3.? Also should Y be deleted from 5. since XZ->Y->B?

Comment: @Leif I think so. You can look at the slide 12 (the rest might be helpful too) here: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~pjm/db/fd-lecture.pdf

Comment: 1. XZ->Y 2. XZ->B 3. YA->C 4. A->G 5. C->W 6. B->G                                                                        I'm just confused about whether or not Y can be deleted from 4. if the implication is derived from XZ.. I'm thinking it should stay.

Comment: @Leif I think so too, since if Y is deleted then the dependency will not be able to construct from the set. Double check if this is homework, though:)

Answer (score 0):

> X->Z (deleted Z attribute, trivial FD)

The trivial part of XZ->Z is Z->Z. I don't think you can derive X->Z from XZ->Z.

If #1 is wrong, this #2 and #3 are also wrong.

Numbers 4-7 in your answer are right. (Your answer that's inside your question, that is.)

From your comment to Ziyao Wei,

> 1. XZ->Y 2. XZ->B 3. YA->C 4. A->G 5. C->W 6. B->G

Number 4 is wrong. Correct it, and you've found the minimal cover. Also, you said

> I'm just confused about whether or not Y can be deleted from 4. if the
>   implication is derived from XZ.

If you post your reasoning--how you derived A->G from XZ->Y and YA->C--then someone can probably show you where your reasoning went astray.